# How to integrate zeromq polling into pyqt main loop?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, zeromq, polling

I've got a simple PySide program (my first GUI program) in which I just have two sliders going from -100 to 100. The first slider sends its value to a hardware controller using zeromq. This controller drives a hardware steering wheel, but since the steering wheel takes some time to adjust its position to the desired position, I receive feedback from that wheel which I now want to reflect into the second slider below it. In this way, the second slider "follows" the first one to show how far the steering wheel actually is:

[image]

Since I both receive and send zeromq messages more or less simultaneously I need to do something with zeromq polling. I worked with that before, but not in a pyqt program. So I am kinda lost on where or how to incorporate the zeromq polling in this program.

The code I have right now is here: http://pastebin.com/8j5TDpkX

Would anybody have some kind of tip or hint on where to incorporate the zmq polling in there?

Comment: I know nothing about zeromq, but you could look at QSocketNotifier for getting a signal on a socket (the zeromq docs talk about this for ioloop). You could also do the polling in a different thread and send signals to the main thread. An alternative is to use a QTimer to send a signal at regular intervals to do the polling.

Answer (score 1):

The old-fashioned way is to use the `ZMQ_FD` option to `zmq_getsockopt(3)` to get an edge-triggered file descriptor that can then be used in other kinds of event loops.